# XMLHttpRequest cannot load, "disallowed scheme for cross-origin requests"

Tags: visualforce, canvas

Our package has a visualforce page that wraps around a canvas app.  For some users, though, the app does not load, with this javascript console error in Chrome:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load. https://emea.salesforce.com/_ui/common/request/servlet/JsLoggingServlet. The request was redirected to a URL ('about:blank') which has a disallowed scheme for cross-origin requests

Any idea why that is?  I think this is different from the other similar questions around "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource".

Comment: Hmm, redirecting to `about:blank`. Interesting.